# Identify a time tunnel story with Old Testament desert shepherds, probably by Philip K. Dick

Tags: story-identification, philip-k-dick

I had read a story, I believe by Philip K. Dick, but stand to be corrected. It is about this office worker who has some kind of a time tunnel through which he communicates with Old Testament desert shepherds.

Can anyone guide me to a name for the story?

Comment: do u mean time machine? time tunnel was a tv show from 1967-- maybe there is another usage?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is [Prominent Author](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58236) by Philip K. Dick, published in 1954. A defective Jiffy-Scuttler provides a doorway to the past. One could regard this as an early example of the religious themes that would become more apparent in his later works.