# Philip K. Dick short story about a man who goes to work via a tunnel

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, philip-k-dick

I'm looking for the title of a Philip K. Dick short story about a man who goes to work via a tunnel. His company allowed him to, so he can get to work by just walking and doesn't have to be stuck in traffic. And he has to report anything weird to his company, but he doesn't... he also sees people inside, tiny people, and can communicate with them.

Comment: Duplicate of [Identify a time tunnel story with Old Testament desert shepherds, probably by Philip K. Dick](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/270518/identify-a-time-tunnel-story-with-old-testament-desert-shepherds-probably-by-ph).

Comment: Also [Science fiction short story about teleportation and a tiny civilization](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/273773/science-fiction-short-story-about-teleportation-and-a-tiny-civilization) though has not been accepted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identify a time tunnel story with Old Testament desert shepherds, probably by Philip K. Dick](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/270518/identify-a-time-tunnel-story-with-old-testament-desert-shepherds-probably-by-ph)

Comment: So "man who goes to work via a tunnel" is the same as "office worker has time tunnel through which he communicates with Old Testament desert shepherds"? God, the SE DUPE rule is pretty stupid.

Comment: @HannoverFist - The goal is to signpost people to the answer. The journey on these isn't especially important because the destination is all.

Answer (score 16):

Could this be *[Prominent Author](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58236)* by Philip K. Dick?

[This review](https://philipkdickreview.wordpress.com/2014/05/10/prominent-author/) mentions the 'small people' that he encounters on his trip through the tunnel.

> Henry Ellis is in a tunnel. The commute is actually not instantenous.
> He has to walk through this tunnel for five steps. The device—the
> Juffi-scuttler—uses travel through the fourth dimension. The
> Juffi-scuttler was developed to solve the growing problem of the
> commute. As more people moved to suburbs, the commutes became longer
> and more odious. The fourth dimension allowed an infinite number of
> Jiffi-scuttlers. Any family that could afford the 1000 credits could
> have one. The only downside was that it was fixed. Each end of the
> Jiffi-scuttler was stuck. Not surprisingly most people used their
> Jiffi-scuttler to travel from home to work. While taking his time
> walking through the tunnel, Henry saw three tiny people, each the size
> of insects. They looked up at Henry with shock. They wore sandals and
> brown robes and looked to him entirely alien. Henry did not want to be
> late for work, so he quickly exited the tunnel and arrived in New
> York.
>
> At the end of the day, Henry talks to Patrick Miller from the research
> office of Terran Development. He was the one who arranged for Henry to
> try out the Jiffi-scuttler to test for any problems before the
> machines would be put on the mass market. He asks for details about
> what goes on in the tunnel and how the transportation is actually
> effected. Unable to articulate his questions and concerns, he prepares
> to go home. Going back into the Jiffi-scuttler, Henry sees another
> group of people, wearing different clothing and slightly taller (six
> inches). They look up in amazement at Henry.
>
> The next morning, Henry goes back to work and sees the small people
> again. This time they were prepared for his arrival. They are also
> writing down something on a very small piece of paper. He takes the
> paper. That day, he asks a colleague in the Research Labs if he can
> borrow a photo microscope. Using it, he takes a closer look at the
> paper and confirms that the small people were writing something on it.
> He uses a translation machine to decode the writing, which turns out
> to be a series of questions. He spends the day answering them and
> running them back through the translator. He gives them the answers on
> the way home.

Comment: First published in Worlds of IF, 1954, available on archive: https://archive.org/details/1954-05_IF/page/n27/mode/2up